# How to post and redirect with Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, response.redirect

I do integration with payment gateway, which required `post method`. So I need to redirect from my page including `post data` to the payment gateway application under `https`

Following by this answer on this questions:

[Post Redirect to URL with post data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31837589/post-redirect-to-url-with-post-data)

[How to make an HTTP POST web request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/how-to-make-an-http-post-web-request/4015346#4015346)

I not able found the right answer for my problem.

I'am using razor pages. Here is my code snippet

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int id)        
        {
            var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "thing1", "hello" },
                { "thing2", "world" }
            };

            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

            var response = await client.PostAsync("https://example/payment/v1/easy", content);

            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return Content(responseString);
        }
```

I successfully get the response, but when I do `return Content(responseString);`. The page just show text only. Any idea how to solved this problem?

Comment: Can you share your response?And what do you want from response?

Comment: I want to redirect to the payment gateway. But that payment gateway required `post method` so I not sure how can be done. The response I get is the payment gateway html page.

Comment: If you want to show html page,you can try to return view() and pass the responseString to the view,use @html.Raw() to change the string to html code.